# How to connect with two database instances (with some rules) (PHP PDO)

Tags: php, database, postgresql, pdo

How can I do this?

The rules are:

- Can exist two databases (master and slave);
- Can exist only one database (master);
- If the query is a SELECT and slave DB is available, the query should be executed on slave DB.
- If the query isn't a SELECT or slave DB isn't available, the query should be executed on master DB.

Some notes:

- Both databases are in the same server
- Databases are in different ports
- The database instance `$db` should be injected in other classes...but which instance? Master or Slave? I don't know yet if the query will be a SELECT or not.

Some doubts:

- Do I need 2 databases instances, right?
- Should I extend PDO prepare method? I think it's a bad practice but it's better than nothing.

Comment: You can connect to two databases but will be able to access one at a time ? I am afraid, its not possible if your looking to access both simultaneously.

Comment: @shashi the connection can be made to one instance at a time (I think I need two instances).

Comment: Yes, make two connection objects and use them as per your need

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an "out of the box" feature for this, But you should be able to build this without a lot of issues,

Create a PHP class which will provide the wanted behavior.
There's no limit on the number of connections to different databases.

So your class should initialize 2 DB connections see (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Create a read function, and a write function. and make sure all of the application I/O runs threw this class.

To make sure you don't need to reconnect everytime, i suggest your make a singleton of your class. see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

your class will look something like this

```
<?php 

class DB {

    protected static $instance = null;
    protected $master;
    protected $slave;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static;
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }

    public __construct(){
        // init master and slave connection
    }

    public read($sql){
        // read slave
        // if not exists read master
    }

    public write($sql){
        // write to master
    }

}
?>
```

Make sure you catch the exception if the connection isn't availible see http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Hope this will get you on your way

Comment: The main point: if you want the kind of functionality you're describing, you'll need to build it. you can create 2 connection's in one instance. if you want to use the DB class (as in the example) anywhere you can just do something like DB::getInstance()->read("Select * from example")

Comment: If you want to have a more specific answer: share some code examples for your situation.